# How do I make my Java 8 application JAWS enabled to help blind users?

Tags: java, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

How do I make my Java 8 application JAWS-enabled to help blind users? I have tool-tips for all options, but a customer who uses JAWS says my application does very little and does not read the tool-tips. How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting tooltip is not working try getAccessibleContext() API. e.g.

```
component.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("This is tooltip.");
```

Also below is official guide from Oracle.
[Rules for Supporting Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/access.html#supporting)